# Visual Studio 2010 - Service Pack 1 Beta rollback?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I recently installed Visual Studio 2010 Premium at my work computer. I'm evaluating the installation of the VS2010 SP1 Beta to adjust many little problems that I've noted in using VS2010.

But I don't know if the SP1 Beta is rollbackable or if If'll have to reinstall all the VS2010 when the final SP1 will arrive to us.

Could anyone advise me about the opportunity to do this?

thanks a lot

rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a copy from the readme file at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=207141 :

> 2.2. Uninstalling
>
> 2.2.1. On computers that have earlier versions of Visual Studio
>
> 2.2.1.1. Uninstalling Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Beta removes features in
>   Visual Studio Tools for Office and
>   Visual Studio Tools for SharePoint
>
> Uninstalling Visual Studio 2010 SP1
>   Beta removes the Visual Studio Tools
>   for Office (VSTO) Design Time and some
>   features of Visual Studio Tools for
>   SharePoint.  The Office and Sharepoint
>   features in Visual Studio 2010 SP1
>   Beta are major upgrades and have
>   different product guids than those in
>   the Visual Studio 2010 original
>   release. Therefore, when SP1 Beta is
>   removed, the features are removed, and
>   the Visual Studio 2010
>   original-release versions must be
>   reinstalled.
>
> To resolve this issue:
>
> In Windows Control Panel, click
>   Uninstall a program. In the list of
>   programs, right-click Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 2010 and then click
>   Uninstall/Change.  In the Maintenance
>   Mode dialog box, click Next and then
>   click Add or Remove Features. Select
>   the following features.    Microsoft
>   Office Developer Tools (x86) or (x64)
>   for Office development. Microsoft
>   SharePoint Developer Tools for
>   SharePoint development. Click Update. 
>   2.2.1.2. Uninstalling Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Beta may not donwload all
>   required packages
>
> When Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Beta is
>   uninstalled by using Add/Remove
>   Programs in the Control Panel, a
>   prompt for source may be displayed. 
>   To avoid this, run setup.exe from the
>   original location, and uninstall by
>   using Setup Maintenence Mode.
>
> To resolve this issue:
>
> Navigate to the original installation
>   location for Visual Studio 2010 SP1
>   Beta . Run setup.exe. Select Remove.

**Update**

Regarding your comment below, yes, I installed VS 2010 SP1 Beta, here are the problems I got:

- I couldn't install Visual Studio SDK - Fixed - I found there was newer version for VS2010SP1Beta that I didn't realize at first.
- I could not install Phone Developer SDK - Fixed as unrelated - I contacted @ScottGU and they said this is test scenario, I downloaded again and it worked as a charm
- Few issues about Resharper or so (can't remember exactly, but minor for sure) - Fixed - I just got a recent build of Resharper.

If this leads to the question "Should I install it?", I'd say, if you need any of the new features in it (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg442059.aspx for listing), then just install it. It's OK. If not, wait for RTM.

BTW,
If you want to discuss your specific SP1 issues instead of uninstall, no problem in that as well :)

Comment: Commenting formatting wouldn't allow me to answer about my experience clearly, so, I added that as an update to the answer. Please check it out. If you want to ask about specific issues instead of uninstall just mention them and I'll see if I can help.

Answer (score 2):

From Scott Hanselman's [blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudioExplosionVS2010SP1BETAReleasedAndContext.aspx):

> •If you install VS2010 SP1 beta, don't
>   uninstall it if you can avoid it.
>   Rather, wait for SP1 final which will
>   upgrade your beta cleanly and leave
>   you in the best state.

Comment: @robob: No, purely because it relies on .Net 4 Beta SP as well. I can't afford to break my development machine :o)